# JavaScript doesn't work with apple-mobile-web-app-capable if add to Home Screen

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, web-applications

I made a full-screen web app with `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">`. If I add the web page to homescreen, all JavaScript stops working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      alert(window.navigator.standalone);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This demo works in Safari, alert false, but if I add the page to Home Screen, then open it from homescreen, no alert, none of the Javascript works. Does anyone know what's wrong with it?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your alert code in a `window.onload` function?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onload?redirect=no

Comment: @BlakeSimpson, no lucky, nothing works.

Comment: Have you tried to debug via the console? If you open up a new version of Safari you can remotely debug the iOS simulator/device using the webkit console. It's under the "develop" menu.

Answer (score 1):

Try to include all the relevant tags in the head section, not only the apple-mobile-web-app-capable.

Answer (score 0):

Alert and Confirm seems to be broken in iOS7 when app is pined to the home screen.

See :
["alert()" and "confirm()" not working with "apple-mobile-web-app-capable"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903525/alert-and-confirm-no-working-with-apple-mobile-web-app-capable)

But javascript is working fine :+)

Answer (score -2):

1. You try to delete cookie and data in Safari in configuration.