# Dialogs not working in iOS 7 full screen web apps

Tags: javascript, iphone, ipad, ios7

Web apps that have an icon saved to the home screen (mobile Safari - iOS 7 only) no longer seem to pause the thread when a dialog is in the method.
For example an

```
'alert('something here')'
```

just gets bypassed, and a

```
var a = confirm('Are you sure')
```

always returns false for 'a' and does not present a dialog.  Dialogs are presented when the web page is not accessed from a homescreen icon.  This is only the case when the page is presented as a full-screen web app.

I have not found any documentation to support this.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's a bug:

see http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/safari-ios7-html5-problems-apis-review

some suggested workarounds here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18925833/1200486

Comment: i thought as much.  Thanks.

Comment: I have an iPad mini with iOS 7.0.3 and the issue is still present in Safari. It works with Chrome, though.

Comment: Issue exists in iOS 7.0.5.